How to Access a Request-Scoped Bean in a Spring Exception Handler?
I need to log trace information using a Tracer bean, which is request-scoped, in both my REST method and exception handler. The Tracer bean is consumed in the REST method to log the trace information at the start of processing the request, and I want to use the same trace message in the exception handler when an exception occurs.
However, I'm facing difficulties accessing the request-scoped Tracer bean in my exception handler.
I have tried both rest controller @ExceptionHhandler annotation in the REST controller and  @ControllerAdvice, but neither seams to support access to a scope bean.
Here's my setup:
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    Tracer tracer(){
        return new Tracer();
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "list")
    public String list(Tracer trace){
        return  trace.getCorrelationId();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "throw")
    public String throwEx(Tracer trace,HttpServletRequest req){
         throw new RuntimeException("Ops");
    }


    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    ResponseEntity<String> defaultExceptionHandler(Tracer tracer, HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    
        return ResponseEntity
                .internalServerError()
                .body("ERROR: " + tracer.getCorrelationId());

    }
}

The tracer (for completeness):
@Getter
public class Tracer {
    private final String requestId;
    private final String correlationId;


    public Tracer() {
        requestId = null;
        correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    public Tracer(String requestId, String correlationId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.correlationId = correlationId;
    }
}

Here the test:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testExceptionHandler() throws Exception {
  
        mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/throw")
                )
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString();            
    }
}

And here is the problem:

Could not resolve parameter [0] in org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.baeldung.scopes.MyController.defaultExceptionHandler(com.baeldung.scopes.Tracer,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception): No suitable resolver

It seems that I cannot directly inject the Tracer bean into the exception handler method.
I'm I missing something here?
Is there another approach to do this problem?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you actually read the exception? You cannot autowire request scoped beans (or any scope actually) into methods like that. That will only work for @Bean methods in @Configuration files. Just wire it as a field in the controller or class that needs it.

The bean works if injected into a method parameter, and a new instance is created at each http request, so I assumed it is correctly inserted into the Spring framework. Anyway, I will give a try to check.

It doesn't work correctly, it creates a new instance if you use it in a method argument it will not use the request scoped instance. Also the @BEan for the Tracer should be in an @Configuration not the controller itself.

Yap, you are right. I never suspected that couldn't inject the bean from inside the controller. It works as it supposed to, if declared in config and auto wired. Also, doesn't make much sense autowired, but I can understand how it works.

It makes perfectly sense (and you should have read the documentation instead of making assumptions as it is explained in there how scoped proxies work). The same way works in CDI (regular Java injection) as well.

Sorry if I sounded offensive, but that was not my intention. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Most correct way is this
Maybe "dirty", but at least it works:
@Getter
public class YourException extends RuntimeException {

  private final Tracer tracer;
  
  //Your constructors
}

@GetMapping(path = "throw")
public String throwEx(Tracer trace,HttpServletRequest req){
  throw new YourException("Ops", tracer);  -- pass your tracer to the constructor
}


@ExceptionHandler({YourException.class})
ResponseEntity<String> defaultExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, YourException ex) {
    
  return ResponseEntity
        .internalServerError()
        .body("ERROR: " + ex.getTracer().getCorrelationId());

}

Other solution is ThreadLocal (spring web-mvc uses thread-per-request model)
public class TracerInfo {
  private static final ThreadLocal<Tracer> TRACER = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void set(Tracer tracer) {
    TRACER.set(tracer);
  }

  public static Tracer get() {
    return TRACER.get();
  }
}

@GetMapping(path = "throw")
public String throwEx(Tracer trace,HttpServletRequest req) {
  TracerInfo.set(tracer);
  throw new YourException("Ops");
}

@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
ResponseEntity<String> defaultExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    
  return ResponseEntity
        .internalServerError()
        .body("ERROR: " + TracerInfo.get().getCorrelationId());

}

Ps: fix compile error if any since I do not have IDE right now

Thanks. From what I read about it, the scoped beans are stored as thread attribute, so any way to access it, under the hood, would be the same.

Overly complex. Just inject the Tracer as a field in the components you want to use it, this will inject a proxy, which will delegate to the instance available in the request. This is also how it is documented in the Spring reference guide. This solution adds too much complexity and unnecassary code.

Another approach. Add annotations @RequestScope and @Component to Tracer:
@Getter
@Component
@RequestScope
public class Tracer {
    private final String requestId;
    private final String correlationId;

    public Tracer() {
        requestId = null;
        correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public Tracer(String requestId, String correlationId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.correlationId = correlationId;
    }
}

Inject it in your controller, and remove the trace method parameters.
@RestController
@Log4j2
public class MyController {

    private Tracer tracer; // use instance variable

    public MyController(Tracer tracer) {
        this.tracer = tracer;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "list")
    public String list() {
        return tracer.getCorrelationId();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "throw")
    public String throwEx(HttpServletRequest req) {
        log.info(tracer.getCorrelationId());
        throw new RuntimeException("Ops");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    ResponseEntity<String> defaultExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {

        return ResponseEntity
                .internalServerError()
                .body("ERROR: " + tracer.getCorrelationId()); // use the instance variable

    }
}


That is not another approach it is the only correct approach.
